# spring add default value to form:select

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a spring application, now I've added a dropdownlist to one of my jsp pages using:

```
<form:select multiple="single" path="users[y.count-1].X" items="${Y}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
```

Now I'd like to add the default value "Nothing selected", however I can't seem to find how to do this.
I've tried:

```
<form:select multiple="single" path="users[y.count-1].X" items="${Y}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name">
   <form:option value="Nothing selected" />
</form:select>
```

But "Nothing selected" isn't displayed in my dropdownlist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
<form:select multiple="single" path="users[y.count-1].X" >
   <form:option value="Nothing selected" />
   <form:options items="${Y}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line before your options:

```
<form:option selected="true" value="..." />
```

Comment: Value of attr. selected is not in fact important. You can write there "selected" or whatever you want. You can not do something like
<form:option selected="true" value="1" />
and
<form:option selected="false" value="2" />
... in this case will be selected option with value 2.