# How to set default value to form:select tag in spring

Tags: forms, select, spring-mvc

Can someone tell me how to set default value in form:select tag in spring?

I have four auctions.
1) Normal
2) Reverse
3) French
4) Dutch

I am using spring's form:select and form:options tag for the same.

But now the requirement is that Normal should be selected by default.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
<form:select path="auction">
    <c:forEach items="${auctions}" var="auc" varStatus="status">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${auc.id eq '1'}">
                <option value="${auc.id}" selected="true">${auc.name}</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${auc.id}">${auc.name}</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose> 
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Comment: this is the right answer I dont know why it hasnt been chosen +1

Answer (score 1):

see the SO- entry below:

[spring add default value to form:select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766382/spring-add-default-value-to-formselect)

Comment: I saw this post but I was not able to understand what the X and Y are

Comment: that's not important. the issue is, that the object (form backing object) to which your form element is bound, must be initialized.

Comment: See the example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr> 
   <td id="lado">Estacion :</td>
   <td>
       <form:select path="estacion">
           <form:option selected="selected" value="Primavera">Primavera</form:option>
           <form:option value="Verano">Verano</form:option>
           <form:option value="Otoño">Otoño</form:option>
           <form:option value="Invierno">Invierno</form:option>
       </form:select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Abel. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. In order to make it as useful as possible, please consider adding a description of your code so other users know what it does and why.